# what's wrong with my code on mysql?

Tags: mysql

Target:Titre and Textedesc in French of different biens

```
Biens [ RefBien, Titre, Situation, GPS, EnPeril, DateInsc, Superficie, IdPhotoPrinc#,TypeBien ]
Langues [ IdLangue, Libelle ]
DescriptionsBiens [ RefBien#, IdLangue#, TexteDesc ]
```

what's wrong with my code?

```
SELECT  `TexteDesc` ,  `Titre` 
FROM  `pi_descriptionsbiens` ,  `pi_biens` 
where`pi_descriptionsbiens`.`RefBien` =  `pi_biens`.`RefBien` 
and`IdLangue` = ( SELECT  `IdLangue` FROM  `pi_langues` WHERE  `Libelle` =  "français" ) 
group by `RefBien`;
```

Comment: Maybe replace = with IN.Whats the error?

Comment: How many rows in your tables?

Comment: replace = with IN dosent work

Comment: Post some sample data or even a screenshot of both tables.

Comment: refbien 1229 titre Crac des Chevaliers et Qal’at Salah El-Din
Municipalitées de Al Hosn et de Haffeh Gps N34 46 54 E36 15 47

Comment: Put in in your question.

Comment: idlangue 2 libelee francais

Answer (score 0):

You shold use  a join instead, and replace `"` with `'`

```
SELECT TexteDesc , Titre, pi_descriptionsbiens.RefBien
FROM pi_descriptionsbiens
JOIN pi_biens ON pi_descriptionsbiens.RefBien = pi_biens.RefBien 
and IdLangue=(SELECT IdLangue FROM pi_langues WHERE Libelle = 'français') 
group by pi_descriptionsbiens.RefBien;
```

Also, make sure this returns a value

```
SELECT IdLangue FROM pi_langues WHERE Libelle = 'français'
```

Comment: Unknown column ' Titre' in 'field list'

Comment: SELECT TexteDesc , Titre 
FROM pi_descriptionsbiens pi_biens  Not unique table/alias: 'pi_biens'

Comment: are the table name biens or pi_biens?

Comment: there is pi_biens , i think the problem is "Titre is only show in pi_biens ,not in descriptionsbiens

Comment: Are you sure you executed the correct syntax? `SELECT TexteDesc , Titre FROM pi_descriptionsbiens pi_biens` is not what i suggested as answer. Try again!

Comment: sry i missclick. Thank you!:-D  how can i do,if i want to have RefBien in my result?

Comment: Just add it to the select. `SELECT TexteDesc , Titre, RefBien `

Comment: Since that field exists in both tables, you need to determine which table to use from. Since you group on pi_descriptoinsbiens, use this syntax, `SELECT TexteDesc , Titre, pi_descriptionsbiens.RefBien`

Comment: u mean SELECT TexteDesc , Titre FROM pi_descriptionsbiens pi_biens?  it will bring "Not unique table/alias: 'pi_biens'"

Comment: No thats what you wrote. I simply commented a SELECT. nevermind, use the query in my answer.

Comment: You have to accept my answer as correct, dont post a new answer here as it will be removed! You can accept a answer but clicking the green icon under the up/down vote of my answer/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're after something like this...

```
  SELECT DISTINCT TexteDesc 
                , Titre  
             FROM pi_descriptionsbiens d
             JOIN pi_biens b
               ON d.RefBien =  b.RefBien 
             JOIN pi_langues l
               ON d.IdLangue = l.IdLangue 
            WHERE l.Libelle = "français"
```

Comment: What a beautiful way to write the SQL syntax. I will adapt this.